# How to submit a Hadoop streaming job and check execution history with Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, mrv2

I am newbie to Hadoop. In Hadoop 1.X, I can submit a hadoop streaming job from master node and check the result and execution time from the namenode web.

The following is the sample code for hadoop streaming in Hadoop 1.X:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input myInputDirs \
-output myOutputDir \
-mapper /bin/cat \
-reducer /bin/wc
```

However, in Hadoop 2.x, the job tracker is removed. How can I get the same feature in Hadoop 2.X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hadoop 2.0, you can view the jobs in multiple ways

1) View the jobs from ResourceManager UI ResourceMnagerhostname:8088/cluster
2) View the jobs from HUE - HUEServerHostname.com:8888/jobbrowser/
3) From command line (once the job is completed)

usage: yarn logs -applicationId  [OPTIONS]

general options are:
 -appOwner    AppOwner (assumed to be current user if
                                 not specified)
 -containerId      ContainerId (must be specified if node
                                 address is specified)
 -nodeAddress      NodeAddress in the format nodename:port
                                 (must be specified if container id is
                                 specified)
Example: yarn logs -applicationId application_1414530900704_0005

Comment: As my testing machines is limited to 2GB memory, can i use yarn to test?

Comment: 2GB is very less. But, you can give it a try.